# I can't read files in C - my program keeps crashing on run-time. Any solutions?

Tags: c, windows, file, io, runtime-error

Every time I try to read a file with `fopen` my program crashes.

Here is the line of code:

```
FILE *stopwatch = fopen(("C:/Users/Erlandas/Desktop/Research/C/TestNo%i/ProgramNo1/ProgramNo1Stopwatch.txt", currentTest), "w+")
```

I also use `fclose`.

When I take away both of those lines, the program starts working again.

I am using `Code::Blocks` because I can't get C and C++ set up on Eclipse.

Comment: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: check the warnings you get (on line 23). This is not python, you cannot format strings like that.

Comment: So i could format a string in a char array and then put the destination in fopen?

Comment: @ErlandasAksomaitis What do you think `("C:/Users/…/ProgramNo1Stopwatch.txt", currentTest)` evaluates to?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: @melpomene thanks for the backup :)

Answer (score 3):

This is not doing what you're expecting.

You're expecting to generate a filepath on the fly and pass it to `fopen` but this is not Python.

So your construct

```
FILE *stopwatch = fopen(("C:/Users/Erlandas/Desktop/Research/C/TestNo%i/ProgramNo1/ProgramNo1Stopwatch.txt", currentTest), "w+");
```

is equivalent to (because of the way `,` works with multiple statements: the last one is returned in that case):

```
FILE *stopwatch = fopen(currentTest, "w+");
```

`currentTest` being an integer, you get a ton of warnings (who cares about warnings :)) and finally a crash because `fopen` mistakes your integer for a pointer.

You have to use `sprintf` for instance to create a string in a temp buffer, like this:

```
char buf[100];
sprintf(buf,"C:/Users/Erlandas/Desktop/Research/C/TestNo%i/ProgramNo1/ProgramNo1Stopwatch.txt", currentTest);
FILE *stopwatch = fopen(buf, "w+");
```

Comment: sorry, I didn't get any red warnings in Code::Blocks so I assumed everything was ok. Thanks for explaining

Comment: Thanks for the help, but should I clear the array every time after using it when I wan to put in a new destination?

Comment: just sprintf in it again, it will overwrite previous data. Be careful of the size. 100 may not be enough for large paths.

Comment: BTW you should check the options of code::blocks. Maybe the warnings are _off_. Bad idea!